# Div Expansion and contraction on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am making a drop down menu with jquery animate effect,

```
var mexpand = false;
function toggleMenu() {
    if (!mexpand) {
        $('jQuery selector').css({ "background": "url('Images/bnbgmenu.jpg') repeat-x top left" });
        $("#NavDiv").animate({ height: "200px" });
        mexpand = true;
    }
    else {
        $("#NavDiv").animate({ height: "35px" });
        $('jQuery selector').css({ "background": "url('Images/bnbguser.jpg') repeat-x top left" });
        mexpand = false;
    }
}
```

Kindly have a look on this     [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hp4jh9f7/2/)

I want to hover on menu icon to expand and I want to contract when mouse leaves the drop down menu.

but I am facing problems with mouseover and mouseout which you can see in fiddle.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to remove all that unrelated code from the fiddle, like `myVar = setInterval(function()...`, that seems to have no function at all

Comment: I think your life would be easier if you use a showMenu and a hideMenu funciton instead of the toggleMenu, as they are being called in different places anyhow. And start with a simple example, and make sure you understand it. You Fiddle contains a lot of irrelevant stuff that might be confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the function, you can set functionality with jQuery.
Give your icon image the class `icon` and then use following jQuery.

```
$( ".icon" )
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $("#NavDiv").animate({ height: "200px" });
    }
);
$("#NavDiv")  
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({ height: "35px" });
    }
);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/hp4jh9f7/4/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave` events instead of `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` respectively.

see this fiddler  http://jsfiddle.net/hp4jh9f7/2/